# Checkbox needs to be aligned with label tag

Tags: css, html

I am trying to align my `checkbox` with my `label` text. [Here is my snapshot of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqOoX.jpg).

I am using a checkbox which will display the drop-down list only if it is checked.

```css
select {
  visibility: hidden;
}

input {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + select {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<label>Applying for masters</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="masters">

<select>
  <option>Select</option>
  <option>CS</option>
  <option>EC</option>
  <option>IT</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.
Wrap your check boxes in one `div` element and apply CSS on that class.

Set style`vertical-align: middle`

```html
  <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            select {
                visibility: hidden;
            }
    
            input {
                margin-left: 5px;
            }
                input[type=checkbox]:checked + select {
                visibility: visible;
            }
            /* new style to align check box */
            .checkboxes input {
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
    
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- new div tag to wrap all check boxes inside it -->
      <div class="checkboxes">
         <label for="masters">Applying for masters</label>
         <input type="checkbox" id="masters" value="yes" name="masters">
         <select>
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>CS</option>
            <option>EC</option>
            <option>IT</option>
         </select>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```